# ValueError: Could not lookup TPU metadata from name 'b'usman''. Please doublecheck the tpu argument in the TPUClusterResolver constructor

Tags: keras, permissions, tpu

My code worked well on TPU but now it generates this permission denied error. My TPU machine and local VM is in the same region. Moreover, I also fulfill all the authentication requirements. The logs are attached below. Your help is highly appreciated Thanks.

[=Log Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNSfO.png)